# How does a file read looks like in gdb

Tags: gdb, reverse-engineering

When a program reads from a file, how does this looks like in GDB. I know that the file has t o be opened etc.

Also something like this:

```
call fopen
...
call fread
...
call fclose
```

but can you explain me the "copy bytes from file to program memory" action? perhaps with an example of assembly. 
In which registers are the adresses of the file/of the programm memory where the file content is stored.
fopen returns a handle. How can i track that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily check this by yourself by simply writing a small `C` program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char c;
    FILE *f = fopen("hello.txt", "r");
    c=fgetc(f);
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Then compile it with a switch to output assembly, for gcc: `gcc -S -O0 hello.c` (the `-S` tells gcc to output assembly, the `-O0` disables the optimizer).
Then have a look at `hello.s` and you will see the assembly generated for this code:

```
...
subq    $16, %rsp
movl    $.LC0, %esi
movl    $.LC1, %edi
call    fopen
movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)
movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
movq    %rax, %rdi
call    fgetc
movb    %al, -9(%rbp)   <--- here a byte gets moved from a register to variable c
movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
movq    %rax, %rdi
call    fclose
...
```

Essentially the function `fgets` or `fgetc` is called and the result is copied back to your variables. You can easily check the generated code on your platform with your compiler and the input method you are interested in.

Note that there may be more possible assembly variants if other libraries are used for input.

If the optimizer was used when the program was compiled, the assembly might even look more strange.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it seems like you are looking to learn assembly. Fopen return a handle to the file. When you will call Fopen, and basically many other functions the return value will be placed in the EAX register, but it depends of hardware also. So if you want to track a handle of a file, after calling fopen in ASM you should get it from EAX register. If you are intersted in more details you should look up for some tutorials or books of assembly. For example [Assembly Programming tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/index.htm)